# Passing argument to array.prototype.findIndex(callback[, thisArg])

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am having trouble passing an argument to the javascript array.prototype.findIndex(callback[, thisArg]) API. The javascript documentation specifies that an argument can be passed but I have not had luck. 
This is the API reference [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

I see this syntax in API:

```
arr.findIndex(callback[, thisArg])
```

This is my current implementation but I don't like the way it is implemented with a globally created variable it is not easibly tested code.

```js
var vm = this; //angular context
//List of objects
vm.someList = [{storeId: "1", name:"Carmel", quantity:"25", orderNumber:"12345"},
         {storeId: "2", name:"Chocolate", quantity:"25", orderNumber:"23456"},
         {storeId: "3", name:"Vanilla", quantity:"25", orderNumber:"34567"},
         {storeId: "4", name:"Cinnamon", quantity:"25", orderNumber:"45678"}];
  
//List of items marked with priority
vm.priorityList = [{storeId: "3", name:"Vanilla", quantity:"25", orderNumber:"34567", priority: "true"}];
  
//For loop finds index of criteria to perform operation on someList[i] element
for(var i =0; i < vm.priorityList.length; i++){
 //itemToFind created in global scope.
        vm.itemToFind = vm.priorityList[i];
 var index = vm.someList.findIndex(findPriorityIndex);
 //Don't worry about the operation being performed.
    console.log(index);
}

//callback fn used
function findPriorityIndex(element, index, array){
     return (element.storeId === vm.itemToFind.storeId
        && element.orderNumber ===vm.itemToFind.orderNumber);
}
```

I have tried to pass the argument to be used as thisArg in the callback with the following syntax but all resulted in failed attempts. Also I do acknowledge the API mentions the argument will be referenced as this inside the callback, and I have made such adjustment in the callback function.

```
vm.someList.findIndex(findPriorityIndex[, vm.priorityList[i]]);
vm.someList.findIndex(findPriorityIndex(vm.priorityList[i]));
vm.someList.findIndex([findPriorityIndex, vm.priorityList[i]]);
```

If anyone can provide any information as to how the argument should be passed to the callback function I will greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically you set with `thisArg` of findIndex, `this` in the callback.

```
for (var i = 0; i < vm.priorityList.length; i++) {
    index = vm.someList.findIndex(findPriorityIndex, vm.priorityList[i]);´
    //                                   set thisArg ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    console.log(index);
}

// callback fn used
function findPriorityIndex(element, index, array) {
    return element.storeId === this.storeId && element.orderNumber === this.orderNumber;
    //        access this here ^^^^                                and ^^^^
}
```

Comment: Thank you that is the answer I was exactly looking for. I wonder why the API says the syntax is in another manner
?

Comment: Ok well I am glad you know the correct syntax. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TerNovi FYI the syntax `arr.findIndex(callback[, thisArg])` means only that the `thisArg` param is optional. ;)

Comment: ES6 caveat: make sure you use a function like in the code above because ```const findPriorityIndex = (element, index, array) => { etc.. }``` won't work. In this case ```this``` will be set to ```Window```. This tripped me up...

Answer (score 3):

In simple words, use **this** to access the argument as explained below

```
const fruits = [{id:1,label:"apple"},{id:2,label: "banana"}, {id:3,label:"cantaloupe"}
            ];
function checkIndex(element) {

    return element.label == this;
}

console.log(fruits.findIndex(checkIndex,'banana'));
```

Comment: This is an excellent and simple solution. You can add this.toString() for Angular. Just verified this.